# How to implement the observer pattern for REST API's? (Between Frontend and backend)

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-web-api

I want to subscribe once to API and and i should get multiple response from API until i unsubscribe that event. 
i) First of all. Is it possible ?
ii) If yes then how ? If no then why it is not a following observer pattern's guidelines ?

I have tried to use yield keyword but it does not help.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use forkJoin.
Something similar:
https://medium.com/@swarnakishore/performing-multiple-http-requests-in-angular-4-5-with-forkjoin-74f3ac166d61

Comment: my task is time consuming task and i need a progress of that task at particular time. thats why forkjoin is not my option.

Comment: Is better your answer say on comment.